# Get-AzureStorageBlob without -blob parameter returns images twice

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

It seems like the `Get-AzureStorageBlob` cmdlet returns two items with the same name (but different ContentType) when I omit the `-blob`  parameter (to retrieve all images):

Now when I use the `Where-Object` cmdlet to retrieve a specific blob by name I get two blobs back:

[image]

If I instead specify the blob name in the `Get-AzureStorageBlob` cmdlet, I only get one file back:

[image]

Is this behavior desired? Also in the Azure Storage Explorer I only see one item.

This is how the Request without the `-blob` parameter looks like:

```
GET https://XXX.blob.core.windows.net/XXX?restype=container&comp=list&prefix=&maxresults=5000&include=snapshots%2Cmetadata%2Ccopy HTTP/1.1
x-ms-version: 2017-04-17
x-ms-client-request-id: Azure-Storage-PowerShell-XXX
User-Agent: Azure-Storage/8.5.0 (.NET CLR 4.0.30319.42000; Win32NT 10.0.15063.0) AzurePowershell/v5.0.0
x-ms-date: Fri, 16 Mar 2018 08:32:56 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey XXX
Host: XXX.blob.core.windows.net
```

Comment: Can you trace the request/response through a tool like Fiddler and share the request URL and output?

Comment: @GauravMantri give me a sec

Comment: @GauravMantri I added the request but omit the response since it contains sensitive data. Maybe it has something to do with the include snapshot parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Verify case. `-Blob` items are case-sensitive. PowerShell `where -eq ...` is not case sensitive.

Perhaps the two JPG of the first example differ only in some characters case.

Comment: Pretty answer !